# Capcha not getting displayed

Tags: themes, captcha

I am using the theme Feed Engine for a question and answers site. I am having a problem that it is not displaying the captha(see [here](http://www.technology-arena.com/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword)). I would be very thankful if someone could help me out. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Here is the file `CaptchaSecurityImages.php` which gives error on line `34`

```
<?php
session_start();
class CaptchaSecurityImages {
   function generateCode($characters) {
      /* list all possible characters, similar looking characters and vowels have been removed */
      $possible = '23456789bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyz';
      $code = '';
      $i = 0;
      while ($i < $characters) { 
         $code .= substr($possible, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible)-1), 1);
         $i++;
      }
      return $code;
   }
   function CaptchaSecurityImages($width='120',$height='40',$characters='6') {
      $font = "monofont.ttf";
      $code = $this->generateCode($characters);
      /* font size will be 75% of the image height */
      $font_size = $height * 0.75;
      $image = imagecreate($width, $height) or die('Cannot initialize new GD image stream');
      /* set the colours */
      $background_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
      $text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 20, 40, 100);
      $noise_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 100, 120, 180);
      /* generate random dots in background */
      for( $i=0; $i<($width*$height)/3; $i++ ) {
         imagefilledellipse($image, mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), 1, 1, $noise_color);
      }
      /* generate random lines in background */
      for( $i=0; $i<($width*$height)/150; $i++ ) {
         imageline($image, mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), $noise_color);
      }
      /* create textbox and add text */
      $textbox = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0, $font, $code) or die('Error in imagettfbbox function');
      $x = ($width - $textbox[4])/2;
      $y = ($height - $textbox[5])/2;
      imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, $x, $y, $text_color, $font , $code) or die('Error in imagettftext function');
      /* output captcha image to browser */
      header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
      imagejpeg($image);
      imagedestroy($image);
      $_SESSION['security_code'] = $code;
   }
}
$width = isset($_GET['width']) && $_GET['width'] < 600 ? $_GET['width'] : '120';
$height = isset($_GET['height']) && $_GET['height'] < 200 ? $_GET['height'] : '40';
$characters = isset($_GET['characters']) && $_GET['characters'] > 2 ? $_GET['characters'] : '6'; 
$captcha = new CaptchaSecurityImages($width,$height,$characters);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have problem in font files path.

Just check [this link](http://www.technology-arena.com/wp-content/themes/working/feedbackengine3/data/CaptchaSecurityImages.php?width=100&height=35&characters=5). Please fix your font path.

You can check [this page](http://drupal.org/node/147854) for reference. Read the comment section of this page.

Thanks